# Fetch drop down box multi selector

Tags: jsp-tags

I have written this program to **fetch the drop down multi selector** data from the data base and show all the options of multi selectors with highlighting the selected ones with the rest options.

```
 <% String[] skills=(String[])request.getAttribute("skills");
            //skills[]={"Core Java","Hibernate","Sql}; // it is dynamic d
            String[] allSkills={"Core Java","J2ee","Spring","Hibernate","Sql",".net"}; 
        %>

        <tr>
        <td>Skills Known</td>
            <td><select name="skills" multiple STYLE="width: 148px">
            <% for(int i=0;i<allSkills.length-1;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<skills.length-1;j++){
                if(allSkills[i].equals(skills[j])){%>
        <option value=<%=allSkills[i] %> selected="selected"><%=allSkills[i] %></option>
                            <%return; %>    
                <%}else if(j==skills.length-1){%>
                <option value=<%=allSkills[i] %>><%=allSkills[i] %></option>
                <%}
                        }
                    }%>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%
```

/* get the skills as a array from the data base*/

```
String[] skills = (String[]) request.getAttribute("skills");
```

/* write all the options availbale in the drop do*/

```
String[] allSkills = { "Core Java", "J2ee", "Spring", "Hibernate", "Sql", ".net" 
>%
```

/* the code for multiple selector will be */

```
   <tr>
            <td>Skills Known</td>
        <td><select name="skills" multiple STYLE="width: 148px">
                            <%
        for (int counter = 0; counter < allSkills.length; counter++) {
                                    int status = 0;
                                    for (String str : skills) {

                                        if (!(str.equalsIgnoreCase(allSkills[counter]))) {
                                            continue;
                                        } else {
                                            status++;

                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (status > 0) {
                            %>
                            <option value="<%=allSkills[counter]%>" selected="selected"><%=allSkills[counter]%></option>
                            <%
                                } else {
                            %>
                            <option value="<%=allSkills[counter]%>"><%=allSkills[counter]%></option>
                            <%
                                }

                                }
                            %>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
```